# Any way to get Night Shift to work on external monitors?

Tags: macos, mac, color-profiles, displaylink

I have external monitors connected via DisplayLink from my MacBook Pro M1 (macOS Monterey 12.2.1)

Night Shift and [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) won't work on the external displays (it only affect the main display)

Anyone know any workaround to help my eyes?
(Or is there any way to adjust external display colors at all?)

**UPDATE:**

Thx to Tetsujin, I also tried [Display Calibrator Assistant to change color temperature](https://www.maketecheasier.com/adjust-color-temperature-mac/). But it didn't work either:

[image: error]

The color profile was still saved and I can select it, just like I can select flux profile, but they have no effect.

Comment: You can use colour temperature. On phone, full answer later

Comment: @Tetsujin Thx a lot! I was really excited but it didn't work :'(

Comment: That's maybe a perms issue. I've no idea why it wouldn't save. I don't have Monterey on anything here, so can't test, but it's a pretty basic requirement that you can save .icc profiles for your displays.

Comment: It saved, I can now select the new profile, but it has no effect. I updated my original question with the screenshot of the error. Thx anyway!

Comment: It still looks like some sort of permissions issue. It's not that the .icc method doesn't work, it's that your system is refusing for some unknown reason to apply it to the display. I honestly have no clue as to why that might be. It is a basic requirement of display management.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using DisplayLink(D6000S) and flux in fact works for me on both displays.

https://support.displaylink.com/forums/287786-displaylink-feature-suggestions/suggestions/18840574-support-night-shift-and-f-lux-for-mac-os

When you install it ofc.

I'm on Release: 1.8  of DisplayLink.